Deploy of app Angular in IIS windows server 2019
i got dist with my project using --ng build
and i'm trying to deploy in IIS service but i have troubles to show the page on localhost: port 81, the page is on blank an i trying to saw this code in xampp an is correct compiled, i install nodejs 20.13.1 LTS an the app was built on the angular 16.2.0 therefore t
The page doesnt have response on the page i only saw the information that is on the directory the inly thing that i saw the favicon created everyone know how to fixed my deplyment  i try web.config and in index href chaging

Does this answer your question? host node js on windows server (iis)

If that's just a simple Angular web app, the steps in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/ are far from enough. You will have to indicate more details of your IIS setup, or this question will be closed.

You need more information to analyze your problem, you can check if there are any relevant error messages in the console or Event Viewer.
